# Impute missing rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe `d1` like:

```
    date         key   value
0   2023-12-01   K0    9
1   2023-12-03   K1    3
2   2023-12-04   K0    10
3   2023-12-01   K1    8
```

How can I efficiently impute rows related to missing dates to get a dataframe like:

```
    date         key   value
0   2023-12-01   K0    9
1   2023-12-02   K0    0
2   2023-12-03   K0    0
3   2023-12-04   K0    10
4   2023-12-01   K1    8
5   2023-12-02   K1    0
6   2023-12-03   K1    3
7   2023-12-04   K1    0
```

Comment: Why must the last row for key `K1` include `2023-12-04` ?

Comment: Probably OP wants a combination of dates and key

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def fn(g, mx, mn):
    r = pd.date_range(mn, mx)
    g["date"] = pd.to_datetime(g["date"])
    g = g.set_index("date").reindex(r).reset_index()
    g["key"] = g["key"].ffill().bfill()
    g["value"] = g["value"].fillna(0).astype(int)
    return g


mx, mn = df["date"].max(), df["date"].min()
out = df.groupby("key", group_keys=False).apply(fn, mx=mx, mn=mn)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       index key  value
0 2023-12-01  K0      9
1 2023-12-02  K0      0
2 2023-12-03  K0      0
3 2023-12-04  K0     10
0 2023-12-01  K1      8
1 2023-12-02  K1      0
2 2023-12-03  K1      3
3 2023-12-04  K1      0
```

Comment: Surely you can find a dupe for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do `merge` with pre-created mapping df.

```
target = pd.merge(pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max()).to_frame(name = 'date'),
                  df[['key']].drop_duplicates(),
                  how='cross')

target = target.merge(df, how = 'left').fillna(0).sort_values(['key'])
        date key  value
0 2023-12-01  K0    9.0
2 2023-12-02  K0    0.0
4 2023-12-03  K0    0.0
6 2023-12-04  K0   10.0
1 2023-12-01  K1    8.0
3 2023-12-02  K1    0.0
5 2023-12-03  K1    3.0
7 2023-12-04  K1    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
(df.set_index(['date', 'key']).unstack(fill_value=0)
 .asfreq('D', fill_value=0).stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
        date key  value
0 2023-12-01  K0      9
1 2023-12-02  K0      0
2 2023-12-03  K0      0
3 2023-12-04  K0     10
4 2023-12-01  K1      8
5 2023-12-02  K1      0
6 2023-12-03  K1      3
7 2023-12-04  K1      0
```